# Connect to PostgreSQL using VB.NET, AJAX and NPGSQL

Tags: ajax, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to write a script in VB.NET and/or .asp that will connect to my PostgreSQL database using the NPGSQL data provider.

This function uses AJAX to get a value (selectedFT) and send that value to the helloWorld.asp script.  This part works fine.

```
function ajaxyThing (selectedFT) {

var xmlhttp; //CREATE THE VARIABLE TO HOLD THE XMLHTTPRequest OBJEcT
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari THESE BROWSERS SUPPORT THE   XMLHTTPRequest OBJECT
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  //CREATE THE XMLHTTPRequest OBJECT
  }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5 THESE BROWSERS DO NOT SUPPORT THE XMLHTTPRequest OBJECT AND NEED    AND ACTIVEXOBJECT
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //CREATE THE ActiveXObject
  }
//When using Async = true specify a function to execute when the reponse is ready in     the onreadystatechange event
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

//TO SEND A REQUEST TO A SERVER, WE USE THE open() AND send() METHODS OF THE     XMLHttpRequest object
xmlhttp.open("GET", "helloWorld.asp?q="+ selectedFT, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Next I need the ASP script (or an .aspx, or an .ashx. I don't know what is the best way) to use the selectedFT value to query my PostgreSQL database. This is where I run into trouble. I know I need to do the following things but I don't know how to put it all together:

1) Get the value from the AJAX http request. For example I should probably use:

```
response.expires=-1
q= request.querystring("q")
```

2) Then I need to establish the connection to the PostgreSQL database. I use the following code (taken from this website http://www.techrepublic.com/article/easily-integrate-postgresql-with-net/6102826) to run in the PageLoad of a standard .aspx page and it works fine to bind the data to a gridview. But what I really need is not to connect the result set to a gridview but have my connection script stand alone so I can use the output to do many different things.   I am not sure how to implement this code in an .asp script (or .aspx, or .ashx) and make it run when I call the .asp script (or .aspx or .ashx) from my AJAX function.

```
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim pgConnection As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection
    Dim pgCommand As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand
    Dim pgConnectionString As String
    Dim sda As NpgsqlDataAdapter

    Dim ds As DataSet
    ds = New DataSet

    pgConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Userid=myUserId;Database=myDatabaseName;password=myPassword;Protocol=3;SSL=false;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20;Encoding=UNICODE;Timeout=15;SslMode=Disable"
    pgConnection.ConnectionString = pgConnectionString
    pgConnection.Open()
    pgCommand.Connection = pgConnection
    pgCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    pgCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ""myTable"";"

    If pgConnection.FullState = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("Connection To PostGres is open", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
    End If

    sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(pgCommand)
    sda.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds
    GridView1.DataBind()

    pgConnection.Close()
End sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I was able to find a solution to this problem. Here is my solution to query from a PostGresql database using the NPGSQL data connector, ASP.NET (VB.NET), Javascript, and AJAX. In my application the AJAX function called "ajaxyThing" receives a value from a custom control in an OpenLayers map but you could pass a value from anything into the function.

Here is the code from the Ajax function in my javascript file:

```
function ajaxyThing (selectedFT) {
var xmlhttp; //CREATE THE VARIABLE TO HOLD THE XMLHTTPRequest OBJEcT
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari THESE BROWSERS SUPPORT THE     XMLHTTPRequest OBJECT
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  //CREATE THE XMLHTTPRequest OBJECT
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5 THESE BROWSERS DO NOT SUPPORT THE XMLHTTPRequest OBJECT AND NEED AND ACTIVEXOBJECT
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //CREATE THE ActiveXObject
}
//When using Async = true specify a function to execute when the reponse is ready in the onradystatechange event
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("divAttributes").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

//TO SEND A REQUEST TO A SERVER, WE USE THE open() AND send() METHODS OF THE     XMLHttpRequest object
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Handler.ashx?q="+ selectedFT, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then in Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010 I created a Web Handler (.ashx) file and passed the variable from my AJAX function into it.
I pass the variable "selectedFT" into the Visual Studio Web Handler. Here is the code from the web handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports Npgsql
Imports System.Data   

Public Class Handler : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    context.Response.Expires = -1
    Dim q = context.Request.QueryString("q") 

    Dim pgConnection As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection
    Dim pgCommand As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand
    Dim pgConnectionString As String
    Dim sda As NpgsqlDataAdapter

    Dim ds As DataSet
    ds = New DataSet

    pgConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Userid=myPostGresUserId;Database=myDatabaseName;password=myPassword;Protocol=3;SSL=false;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20;Encoding=UNICODE;Timeout=15;SslMode=Disable"
    pgConnection.ConnectionString = pgConnectionString
    pgConnection.Open()
    pgCommand.Connection = pgConnection
    pgCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    pgCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ""myTable"" WHERE ""myValue"" = '" & q & "';"

    sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(pgCommand)
    sda.Fill(ds)

    If pgConnection.FullState = ConnectionState.Open Then
        context.Response.Write("<table>")
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = ds.Tables(0)
        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            context.Response.Write("<tr><td><b>Column #1 Name:</b></td><td>" & dr.Item(0) & "</td></tr>") 
            context.Response.Write("<tr><td><b>Column #2 Name:</b></td><td>" & dr.Item(1) & "</td></tr>") 
            context.Response.Write("<tr><td><b>Column #3 Name:</b></td><td>" & dr.Item(2) & "</td></tr>") 
            Next
        ds.Dispose()
        context.Response.Write("</table>")
    Else
        context.Response.Write("pgConnection did not open successfully.")
    End If

    pgConnection.Close()

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

I won't claim that this is the best solution to the problem - but it works. I would be open to any suggestions you may have to make this more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to use NpgsqlParameter instead of doing string concatenation when building your query. By using concatenation you are susceptible to sql injection problems. More info about how to use NpgsqlParameter can be found in the user manual: http://manual.npgsql.org I hope it helps.